# Partially override static member (array) - is this possible?

Tags: php, oop

Lets say I have some base class with static member - array:

```
class BaseClass {
    public static $definition = array(
        'id' => array(type => 'int', 'required' => true),
        'field1' => array(type => 'string', 'required' => true),
        'field2' => array(type => 'bool', 'required' => true),
        // and over8000 array items
    );
}
```

Then I create the child class, and I want to override this static array, BUT I need to chenge only one array item. Is there a way not to copy-paste whole "over8000" items for the sake of only one changed item?

In other words, I want NOT this

```
class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
    public static $definition = array(
        'id' => array(type => 'int', 'required' => true),
        'field1' => array(type => 'string', 'required' => false), // the only changed one
        'field2' => array(type => 'bool', 'required' => true),
        // and over8000 unchanged
    );
}
```

but something more compact, like this:

```
class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
    // yes I know this is invalid, lets call this a "pseudocode"
    public static $definition['field1']['required'] = true;
}
```

Is there a way?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. this member cound be accessed in static context ( `ChildClass::$definition['field1'];` ), so this is not enough to apply change in constructor;

P.P.S. just to clarify: I'm working with engine with all it's "features" as is. And such static members, that even can be accessed in static context - are the parts of engine, that I cant change.

Comment: static array with 8k items? just WOW. I would create class with that items. If you need change them you should not define as STATIC because they are dynamic. Go back to the paper and check if you really need to do that.

Comment: create static method which return desired value from class. It will be more flexible.

Comment: over8000 - is figurative of couse, but there are about 50 items sometimes. What about 'go back to paper' - unfortunately Im working with engine with all it's architecture "features" as is.

Comment: ah .. okey so my answer is its not possible. May be Iam wrong. It is what anyone call this STATIC HELL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a default property value and you can't have any expressions when defining properties. So there is no way to modify the array when defining a child class.

Since it is a static property you can add the following code after class and it will be executed after the class is defined:

```
class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
    public static $definition;
}

ChildClass::$definition = array_merge(BaseClass::$definition, array(
    'field1' => array(type => 'string', 'required' => false)
));
```

Not a good approach but it works if that's what you need.